# How can i change a field in a model as per another field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

Greetings fellow developers.
I have a model candidate.rb and there are 2 columns(offer_code and candidate_type) that i want to work with.
I want the offer_code = "CHP" if the candidate_type = "chapter".
I am trying to do this with after_save but this is creating all the new candidates with candidate_type = "chapter".
I think the condition that I have used is wrong. Please guide me

In candidate.rb

```
After_save : chapter_offer

def chapter_offer
 If self.candidate_type =  "chapter"
    self.offer_code = "CHP"  
 end
end
```

Comment: use `==` for comparison. `self.candidate_type == "chapter"`

Comment: Please check how callbacks works : https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

You need to use before_save callback for this case along with condition check mention by @Alex

Comment: Please paste a reproducible code. There's no such thing as `After_save` or `If` in ruby/rails, neither `:` after a space, unless it's a ternary operation, which isn't your case.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `=` for comparison instead of `==`

And it will be better if you did something like this

```
before_save :chapter_offer, if: -> { candidate_type == 'chapter' }

def chapter_offer
  offer_code = 'CHP'
end
```